# Absolute position doesn't work inside children of flex

Tags: css, flexbox, absolute

I don't know what's wrong.
Here is a short demo of an unexpected behavior :

https://jsfiddle.net/JackIsJack/wfadbu67/16/

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child {
  background-color:red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2<div class="menu"></div></div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Can someone give me a clue ?

Expected behavior : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOMfm.png

Chrome 88.0.4324 (I only use chrome)

Thanks !

Comment: You need to add **position: relative;** in parent then **position: absolute;** will work on child.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position:relative` to parent element of `menu` which has a `child` class:

```
.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give the parent a relative positionning, so it becomes the reference for the absolute child.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child {
  background-color:red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  position:relative;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2<div class="menu"></div></div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent element i.e. element with class `child` should be a **positioned element** for your element with class `menu`.

If you see from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), the definition says the following for an absolutely positioned element  :-

> It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any;
> otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its
> final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and
> left.

In your case , for `child` to be **positioned element**, give it a `position:relative` so that `menu` can now be **absolutely positioned** relative to it (the closest positioned ancestor)

Also **positioned elements** are all elements that do not have the default `position:static` value.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child {
  position:relative;
  background-color:red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2<div class="menu"></div></div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```